# Run and process a while loop while a process is running Java 7

Tags: java, process

I have a C program that sends a message to java program (via MQ) the java program runs another program and sends status messages back to the C program what that other program is running.  The program works and does exactly what I want.  However, I've moved all of this to a new server that is running Java 7 (upgrading java version is not an option now) and I quickly came to discover that the isAlive() method I was using isn't available in Java 7 for the Process class, its only in Java 8.  How would I rewrite this code to work with Java 7

```
try {
   Process p = null;
                        p = run.exec(prog, env, new File(config.getProperty("ROOTDIR")));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        PCHLog.log(new RCReply("C5014", e));
                }
                String dsp = " \\";

                while(p.isAlive()){
                        Messenger.sendMessage(message + dsp, reply2q);
                        if (dsp.equals(" \\")){
                                dsp = " /";
                        }
                        else {
                                dsp = " \\";
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
```

Comment: This question was previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799424/check-if-process-is-running-on-windows-linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799424/check-if-process-is-running-on-windows-linux), you will find an interesting solution. In essence, you ask for `exitValue()` to check if the process is still alive.

```
boolean isRunning(Process process) {
    try {
        process.exitValue();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```