# process isAlive() awlays return false

Tags: java, bash

I have the following process :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "
                        +file.getAbsolutePath() + "/script.sh");
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
                if(p.isAlive()){
                    System.out.print("the process still running");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                }
```

The problem is p.isAlive() always return false even though my process is still running (my script shell is still working).

How to fix it?

Comment: is it helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799424/check-if-process-is-running-on-windows-linux

Comment: How are you sure that it's still running?

Comment: the script.sh opens a bash window and does a job, in the window opened the script is running and the job is being executed.

Comment: Maybe cmd.exe starts bash and then terminates, so only the bash subprocess is running?

Comment: I think that's it, I think it tests if the cmd.exe is still running not the bash subprocess. So how can I test on the subprocess bash if still running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you think the [`START`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command does?

> Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)

So, `exec(...)` **starts a process** for running `cmd.exe`, then the `start` command opens a window and **starts a *second* process** for running `script.sh`, then `cmd.exe` is done and exists, and the `Process` identified by `p` is no longer alive, since that process has ended.

Add `/WAIT`.

> Start application and wait for it to terminate.

```java
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
        "cmd.exe", "/c", "start", "/wait",
        file.getAbsolutePath() + "/script.sh" });
```

Comment: I need a boolean to test if the .sh process is still running. I am going to use that boolean further in my code, so the wait solution is not what I actually need.

Comment: @LSoft Why not? When you add `/WAIT`, the `cmd.exe` program will wait, which means that `p.isAlive()` will now correctly reflect whether `script.sh` is still running.

Comment: Yes now I understand.. it worked perfectly thanks !